# Pasar parámetro mediante ActionLink hacia Controlador

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, mvc, razor

¿Como se pasa el valor de un DropDownList como parámetro por un @Ajax.ActionLink hacia un controlador?
En mi vista cshtml tengo un DropDownList el cual tiene el id del Producto, ese id es cual deseo enviar en el AjaxActionList hacia el controlador. La pregunta es como obtengo ese id y lo paso como parámetro hacia el controlador.

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Agregar +", "AgregarProducto", new { ProductoCodigo = ??? }, new AjaxOptions() {
               HttpMethod = "POST",
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               UpdateTargetId = "listaProductos",
            });
```

En mi controlador "Producto" mi ActionResult "AgregarProducto" debe recibir un parámetro desde la vista:

```
public ActionResult AgregarProducto(int ProductoCodigo)
    {
        int indice = ProductoCodigo;
        if (indice == 0) {
            ....
        }
```

Help me! :-)

Comment: Según lo que pides normalmente el actionlink no debería ser la respuesta que buscas sino un label con stilos de link que ejecute la action por medio de ajax en una función javascript.  Debes agregar un ejemplo de código de lo que ya tienes hecho para ver mejor la lógica que deseas que se realice.

Comment: Añadí código a mi pregunta, espero comprendas mejor.

Comment: De  donde sacaras el valor para la variable  ProductoCodigo esta en el Model o en alguna otra variable que debes extraer de un tag de html. ¿Ademas este valor  cambiara o sera un único valor siempre generado cuando creas el actionlink?

Comment: El valor de ProductoCodigo lo deseo extraer desde un DropDownList (tag html) y este seré variable conforme lo elija en la lista de opciones del combo DropDownList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la información que me brindaste primero deberás  asignar un **id** al  **ActionLink**  y un valor por defecto a tu **ProductoCodigo** y  que de ejemplo uso **__prdid__** (debes poner un valor que no se repita en el string que se generara del actionlink):

```
     @Ajax.ActionLink("Agregar +", "AgregarProducto", new { ProductoCodigo = "__prdid__" }, new AjaxOptions() {
           HttpMethod = "POST",
           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
           UpdateTargetId = "listaProductos",
        },     
        new { id = "linkAdd",onclick="Agregar();" })
```

Tu **ActionLink** deberá realizar la función **Agregar** cuando se le haga click para asi setear el valor del ProductoCodigo  en la  propiedad href.

```
function Agregar() {
    $('#linkAdd').attr('href', function () {
        return this.href.replace('__prdid__', $('#idProd').val()); //idProd es el id de tu DropDownList  
    });
};
```

Recuerda que cuando se de click a tu ActionLink cuando no se haya seleccionado nada al inicio te mandara error de codigo (estas haciendo la referencia una Action que recibe un string  la cual no tienes ) por ello deberás inicializar tu DropDownList con un valor por defecto seleccionado.

Comment: Owwww... excelente buen hombre!!!, por fin, después de varias horas intentándolo. 
Thanks!!!

Comment: una cerveza para este codeador, se lo merece, me salvaste, dale crédito @AntaresV