# Valor de input en routevalue de Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Holas.

Tengo un input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCliente" name="txtCliente" placeholder="Codigo Modular o Nombres" required>
```

Luego un Ajax.ActionLink:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "ValidarCliente", new { Cliente = txtCliente.Value },
                    new AjaxOptions()
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "GET",
                        LoadingElementId = "divProcesando",
                        OnSuccess = "ValidaOnSuccess",
                        OnFailure = "ValidaOnFailure"
                    },
                    new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-success mt-1" })
```

Que al hacer click en este, realice una procedimiento de validación del cliente, pero debo llevar al procedimiento el valor del input "txtCliente".

No me está funcionando definir en el routvalue "Cliente = txtCliente.Value". Podrían apoyarme como lo envío?

Comment: Hola, que modelo (@model ...) tienes definido en la Vista?.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás intentando hacer con el `Ajax.ActionLink()`, no se puede realizar de esa manera.

Estás mezclando lo que es un control de Servidor de ASP.NET MVC (`Ajax.ActionLink()`), con la forma de acceder a los elementos de la página de los WebForms de ASP.NET (`txtCliente.Value`).

Afortunadamente ya existe en StackOverfolw español una pregunta igual a la tuya, con una solución correcta:

[Pasar parámetro mediante ActionLink hacia Controlador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140999/pasar-par%C3%A1metro-mediante-actionlink-hacia-controlador)